# конвертация HEX в строку

Tags: php, php5

Имеется строка 'Привет мир ASCII'.
Я ее конвертирую в массив:

```
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"');
            $s = 'Привет мир ASCII';

    $arr = array();
    $l = mb_strlen($s, 'utf-8');

    // разбить мб строку на массив
    for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++)
    {
        $arr[] = mb_substr($s, $i, 1, 'utf-8');
    }

    // to hex
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    {   
        $hex = '';

        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($arr[$i]); $j++)
        { 
            $hex .= dechex(ord($arr[$i][$j]));
        }

        $arr[$i] = $hex;
    }

   Array(
      [0] => d09f
      [1] => d180
      [2] => d0b8
      [3] => d0b2
      [4] => d0b5
      [5] => d182
      [6] => 20
      [7] => d0bc
      [8] => d0b8
      [9] => d180
      [10] => 20
      [11] => 41
      [12] => 53
      [13] => 43
      [14] => 49
      [15] => 49
   )
```

Как его обратно преобразовать в строку 'Привет мир ASCII'?
**Версия php 5.3.**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer Забыл уточнить, php 5.3.1 )

Answer (score 0):

В общем сделал вот так:

```
echo pack('H*', implode('', $arr)); // хз как, но работает
```